# How can you call one class from another class in php without constantly creating new objects?

Tags: php

I thought I did this correctly with the constructor so I can call one class from another class within each of the functions it has.  I have seen programmers create a new object with every function:

```
function something(){
    $Misc = new Misc();
    $Misc->print($value);
}
```

But that is just a waste.

What am I missing in this PHP code?

```
<?php
class Misc
{


    function __construct() {
        // blank
    }


    function printr($array) {
    // Format array printing

        print'<pre>';
        print_r($array);
        print'</pre>';

    }
}


class TEST
{
    public $Misc;

    public function __construct($params)
    {
        parent::__construct($params);
        $this->Misc   = new Misc();
    }

    public function example($test)
    {
        return $Misc->printr($test);
    }
}

$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo"
);
$createTEST     = new TEST();
$createTEST -> example($array);

?>
```

Comment: You have the answer, but `class TEST` doesn't have a `parent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not putting it in context. Should be..

```
return $this->Misc->printr($test);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/QTpuo

Or in this case you can use a static method.

```
class Misc{
    public static function printr($array) {
        print'<pre>';
        print_r($array);
        print'</pre>';
    }
}
```

and then call it from the other class like this ..

```
class TEST{
    public function example($test){
        return Misc::printr($test);
    }
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/pr27o

Comment: Does it have to be a static function?

Comment: of course not, but this is what static functions are for. there's really no reason to instantiate a whole class.